# In Ansible, how do I export an environment variable in one task so it can be used by another task?

Tags: ansible

Say I have the following file

```
foo.txt
Hello world=1
Hello world=2
...
Hello world=N
```

I want to use Ansible to insert another Hello world line, like this

```
foo.txt
Hello world=1
Hello world=2
...
Hello world=N
Hello world=N+1
```

IOW, I don't know home many Hello world lines there are, I need to find out via script, and get the value of N.

In Ansible, say I have the following shell task

```
- name: Find the last Hello world in foo.txt, and get the value of N
  shell: >
    # Get last Hello world line in foo.txt. I want to export this as an
    # environment variable
    LAST_HW_LINE=`awk '/Hello world/ {aline=$0} END{print aline}' "foo.txt"`
    # Get left side of equation
    IFS='=' read -ra LS <<< "$LAST_HW_LINE"
    # Get the value of N
    NUM=${LS##*\.}
    # Increment by 1. I want to export this as an environment variable
    NUM=$((NUM+1))
```

I want to be able to subsequently do this

```
- name: Add the next Hello world line
  lineinfile:
    dest: foo.txt
    insertafter: "{{ lookup('env', 'LAST_HW_LINE') }}"
    line: "Hello world={{ lookup('env', 'NUM') }}"
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this than using environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Register Variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables)

```
- shell: /usr/bin/foo
  register: foo_result
```

[Registering stdout as ansible variables](https://serverfault.com/questions/537060/how-to-see-stdout-of-ansible-commands)

```
- debug: msg="{{ hello.stdout }}"    
- debug: msg="{{ hello.stderr }}"
```

[Including task with variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse):

```
tasks:
  - include: wordpress.yml wp_user=timmy
```

[Including role with variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles)

```
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - common
    - { role: foo_app_instance, dir: '/opt/a',  app_port: 5000 }
```

---

For your case:

```
- name: so question 39041208
  hosts: '{{ target | default("all") }}'
  tasks:
  - name: Find the last Hello world in foo.txt, and get the value of N
#    shell: awk '/Hello world/ {aline=$0} END{print aline}' "/home/ak/ansible/stackoverflow/q39041208.txt"
    shell: awk '/Hello world/ {aline=$0} END{print NR}' "/home/ak/ansible/stackoverflow/q39041208.txt"
    register: last_line
    ignore_errors: true
  - name: debug
    debug: msg="last line {{ last_line.stdout }}"
  - name: debug next number
    debug: msg="next num {{ last_line.stdout | int + 1 }}"
  - name: Add the next Hello world line
    lineinfile:
      dest: /home/ak/ansible/stackoverflow/q39041208.txt
      insertafter: "{{ last_line.stdout }}"
      line: "Hello world={{ last_line.stdout | int + 1 }}"
```

Comment: How would I do this in my particular example? I'll need to register 2 variables, LAST_HW_LINE and NUM? Or do I split that task up?